# Oracle Adf blank page comes in browser

Tags: oracle-adf

I am working on an ADF application using WebLogic server.

When I run a `jspx page` to test, the browser displays a blank page. Issue is occurring only while using business components, other wise it is working fine with out business components.

Do you have any ideas

Comment: Check for any errors in server logs.

Comment: Have you tried to run in the model tester, it is always a best practice to test by running the application module. See if this issue is persisting even in this tester. Also please provide some logs.

Comment: Is your markup correct? Also, are you using a task-flow?

Comment: How did you create your page ? Do you have <jspx page name>pageDef.xml file ?